# How to set a range of array elements in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

i have an array of zeros

```
declare -a MY_ARRAY=( $(for i in {1..100}; do echo 0; done) )
```

how to set, for example, 12-25th to "1"? i've tried:

```
MY_ARRAY[12..25]=1
MY_ARRAY[12:25]=1
MY_ARRAY[12-25]=1
```

all not working..

the range 12-25 will be variables obtain from another file.
I am looking for a simple solution better not involve in looping

please help

Comment: You must take into account that when declaring an array in the form `( ... )` the index numbering starts in 0, unless you specify the index. e.g. `( [3]="hello" )`. Therefore the 12th element in your `MY_ARRAY` is `${MY_ARRAY[11]}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `eval` here, in this manner:

```
eval MY_ARRAY[{12..25}]=1\;
```

If you want to know what is being `eval`ed, replace `eval` by `echo`.
[Using `eval` is generally considered as a no-no](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). But this use of eval here should be completely safe.

On another note,

```
for i in {1..100}; do echo 0; done
```

can also be re-written as

```
printf '%.1s\n' 0{1..100}
```

EDIT: For start & end being stored in variables, this could work:

```
$ declare -i start=12
$ declare -i end=12
$ eval $(eval echo "MY_ARRAY[{$start..$end}]=1;")
```

But in that case, you should really use loops. This answer is only for demonstration/information.

Comment: Wait another min. here, 12..25 are hard-coded, or are obtained from user? If it's the latter, use of eval may be unsafe...

Comment: thank you!
i dont want to apply for loop in this case,
but i didnt know about eval,
why is it a no-no?

Comment: 12..25  are actually variables that obtain from another file, why is it unsafe?

Comment: See the link i have given for "Using eval is generally considered as a no-no."...

Comment: @once: OP should have clearly mentioned "not looking for a solution involving looping".

Comment: Then the variables that carry 12 & 25 should be declared with `declare -i start; declare -i end` Plus, you should know, that brace expansion cannot contain variables. e.g. `{$start..$end}` will not work.

Answer (score 6):

Simple one-liner:-

```
for i in {12..25}; do MY_ARRAY[$i]=1; done
```

Refer page [`Arrays`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) for more manipulation examples.

If the start & end values are stored in variables, the brace expansion would not work. In that case, you should use for loop like this:

```
$ declare -i start=12
$ declare -i end=25
$ for ((i=$start;i<=$end;i++)); do MY_ARRAY[$i]=1; done
```

Comment: @once: As you mentioned that 12 & 25 are numbers stored in a variable, you would need to use loop. This is this answer you would need to use.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare -a MY_ARRAY=(
                      $(printf "%.2s" 0' '{1..11})    # 11 first zeroes
                      $(printf "%.2s" 1' '{12..25})   # 14 ones
                      $(printf "%.2s" 0' '{26..100})  # remaining zeroes
                    )
```

**update**
If the values 12 and 25 are in two variables, let's say, `From` and `To`:

```
declare -a MY_ARRAY=(
                       $( eval "{ printf %.2s 0_{1..$((From-1))};
                                  printf %.2s 1_{$From..$To};
                                  printf %.2s 0_{$((To+1))..100}; }" |
                                  tr _ ' '
                        )
                    )
```

Comment: Note that the numbers 12, 25 are obtained from a file; i.e. they are in a variable. Brace expansion will not work with them. but OP has not mentioned it originally in the question. so +1

Comment: @anishsane, now I have included another code for that case.